# Can't get dnschef to redirect my target computer to my attacking computer's setoolkit cloned site

Tags: dns

I'm trying to create a fake DNS server by altering my router's DNS IP and redirect it to a fake facebook page using dnschef v0.2 and setoolkit 7.3. I have 2 machines. The first is the attacking computer. It is running Kali 2016.1 in VirtualBox 5.1.0r108711. I am hardwired into a TP-Link TL-WR840N router. The victim's computer is a Windows8.1 machine that is also hardwired into the router. I can't get my victim's computer to get the fake facebook.com. It just goes to the regular one. I've seen countless tutorials so I know what a working output of dnschef and setoolkit looks like. Below are the steps I took troubleshooting wise. Keep in mind this is a brand new install of Kali with default everything.

First things first, I went into my router and made my Primary DNS: 192.168.0.103 for my Kali local IP. And I made the secondary DNS 8.8.8.8 for Google's DNS.

I ran the command to start...

```
dnschef --fakeip=192.168.0.103 --fakedomains=facebook.com --interface=192.168.0.103
```

Looks normal. Then I ran dnschef in a new terminal tab.

Social Engineering>Website Attack Vectors>Credential Harvester Attack>Site Cloner. I used http://www.facebook.com with the IP 192.168.0.103.

I attempted to log into facebook with Internet Explorer on the Windows 8.1 target computer. Nothing happened. I just logged in like normal. I even opened up the harvester file manually. Nothing inside.

Now here's the interesting thing. I go to `var/www/html/index.php` and when I typed in my username and password, I was able to log the username and password with harvester. It works on my local machine but I can't get my second computer to see it.

When I do `nslookup facebook.com` on my Kali machine and my Windows machine, it returns my attacker's address as expective with the real IP as the "Non-authoritative answer. Which means it should be working right!?

I typed in 192.168.0.103 on my target computer and it found the fake page.

So I can conclude that my target computer is seeing facebook.com as my attacker's IP and I can also conclude that I can reach my webpage with my target computer manually. Which means it should have every reason to connect. Yet it is not. I am SOOOO CLOSE. What am I doing wrong!? Any of you guys have any ideas?

Comment: UPDATE: back to square 1. Now Windows 8.1 is not getting the fake page I want it to. Even after clearing the IE cache and the DNS cache. The target computer still crashes when I log in then out of the real facebook in IE.

I also tried to log into my fake page locally with my Kali maching. It wrote to reaver just fine. What's going on!?

Comment: Please do not include additional information in comments. You can [edit](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/133706/cant-get-dnscheff-to-redirect-my-target-computer-to-my-attacking-computers-set) your question and change or include all that is necessary. You don't need to write "update" either, SE keeps the edit history.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using Ettercap. Don't know what the problem was, but I've had nothing but success with various ettercap experiments and starting the apache servers manually.

Answer (score 0):

If the file the `dnschef` created is called `harvester_2016-08-12 01:20:40.379582.txt`, you cannot write the commands as follows:

```
tail ./harvester_2016-08-12 01:20:40.379582.txt
chmod 777 ./harvester_2016-08-12 01:20:40.379582.txt
```

Because it will pass two arguments to the `tail` or `chmod`:

```
harvester_2016-08-12
01:20:40.379582.txt
```

Neither of the above files exists and the commands rightfully return errors.

You need either to quote the whole path or escape the space character:

```
tail "harvester_2016-08-12 01:20:40.379582.txt"
tail harvester_2016-08-12\ 01:20:40.379582.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. I got that fixed. But I still need to have my target see the fake page. I think something is wrong with dnschef.